# fontawesome: stacked icons not displaying correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Here is the plunker - http://plunker.co/edit/ka72zj?p=preview

You can see the delete icon is placed on the right and not in the center. How should it be fixed?

Comment: Do you want it centered in relation to the "Hello Plunker" text?

Comment: oh no, just centered in the square, in which it is contained

Comment: What browser are you seeing this problem in? In Chrome the delete icon is on top of the red one, and is only misaligned by a pixel or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about just minor misalignment (a pixel or two), then that is unfortunately the nature of some icon font glyphs. Absolutely perfect centering vertically or horizontally is quite difficult.

To adjust what you are seeing in Chrome, you can apply the following to the delete icon:

```
left: -1px;
top: -1px;
```

However, this may have negative effects for other browsers.

Comment: that atleast works for Chrome and Safari and I am happy for now with the result :), thank you for your help @JacobMcLock